# Docker build end up with "no space left on the device" error, though there is enough space in one of the disk

Tags: linux, docker, rhel, rhel7

There are 3 disks available for my Linux VM, sda (100GB), sdb (32 GB), sdc(512GB), total 644 GB space available. Details below.

[image]

[image]

Mount point "/var" free space reaching to 0% and Docker build failing with "no space left on device" error, to notice this, "watch -n 0.1 df -H" used in other tab while Docker build happening.

Why it is showing "no space left" error, though there is enough space on sdc ?

Why system unable to use sdb or sdc free space for sda "/var" mount point ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to extend the lvm for /var using sdc, so the logical volume can be increased and /var would have extra space available for use.

An article is available and should help you,

https://www.rootusers.com/how-to-increase-the-size-of-a-linux-lvm-by-adding-a-new-disk/

Comment: Hi Shaquil Ismail thank you.. please tell me.... i am using Azure based RHEL instance. any specific inputs to use free space on sdc ? formatting and partition required on sdc before using it for /var lvm ?

Comment: As long the RHEL instance can recognise there is extra space after using Azure to add more disk space, by running `fdisk -l` then you can create the partition on this new disk space and then you can increase the logical volume which `/var` is using, make sure you have a backup of this instance and read the article thoroughly which I have included in my answer, before performing this task.